# Why Do I Get a Different Result on JSFiddle Than on My Own Page?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm new to JS.

All I want is to have a border with a curved border-radius going around my data. On JSFiddle my code works.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vincej/vr6pokvr/25/)

```js
$(".categories").on('change', function() {

  $("td.cat_products").append('<p> A Very Nice Value</p>').css({
    "background-color": "yellow",
    "border": "solid 1px lightblue",
    'border-radius': "30px"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="categories">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <h4>Add A Product</h4>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cat_products "></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

But on my page, which has the identical code, I get a totally different result - see image. You can see that n on my page it is the `<tr>` which is getting the border. I don't care if it is the `<tr>` or `<td>` I just want a border with a curved radius.  I have tried every imaginable combination of border-radius. It's driving me crazy ! How do I get a nice border with a curved radius on my page ?

[image: My actual page]

Comment: Please fix the fiddle link. Also, if there are any code differences at all, let us know.

Comment: @kirkpatt  Ok - I think it now works .... bloody pain in the butt.

There are no code differences

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap on your page? You're not using it in the fiddle.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I am using it on the whole app, but not in the specific <tr> or <td>   

Possible conflict ?

Comment: But the boostrap classes you have on the table may cause different styling of the `<tr>` and `<td>` within it.

Comment: @Barmar  Looks like you lead me to a solution. I commented out all the BS classes then added them in one by one.  It don't fix it. 

Then I noticed, that other table rows I have elsewhere in the system used the class "form-control" .  When I applied that, I got my rounded border. 

Many Thanks for all your help !!